# Azure Storage account role - DTBUtil_Container_StorageV2

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory

I am working on an Azure Data Lake Storage Gen2 (`ADLSGen2`) account. Inside Azure Portal, in the `Access Control (IAM)` section of this storage account, I see a `Principal` by the name `DTBUtil_Container_StorageV2` that is a member of `Owner` and `Storage Blob Data Contributor` roles.

**Question**: What is `DTBUtil_Container_StorageV2` principal and how does it get created?

Azure Portal Screenshot:
[image]

Comment: Could you please include the Portal screenshot of what `DTBUtil_Container_StorageV2` principal you are referring to?

Comment: @Sridevi Per your request, screenshot added.

Answer (score 0):

> What is `DTBUtil_Container_StorageV2` principal and how does it get created?

The process of creating `DTBUtil_Container_StorageV2` depends on the specific practices and procedures of your organization. It could have been created manually by an **Azure AD administrator**, or it could have been created as part of an automated provisioning process. If you have access to Azure AD, you can check there to get more information about the `DTBUtil_Container_StorageV2` principal.

**Go to portal -> Microsoft Entra ID -> Enterprise applications -> Type the App name.**

Now you can see the service principal properties.

[image]

The roles assigned to `DTBUtil_Container_StorageV2` determine the level of access it has to the ADLSGen2 account.

- The `Owner` role grants full access to the account.
- The `Storage Blob Data Contributor` role grants permissions to read, write, and delete blobs and containers in the storage account.

After assigning a role to the storage account, now you can see the same as your screenshot in my environment.

**Portal:**
[image]

**Reference:**

You can refer to this link to learn how the service principal is created and they are assigning their roles.

- [Quickstart: Register an app in the Microsoft identity platform - Microsoft identity platform | Microsoft Learn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/entra/identity-platform/quickstart-register-app)
- [Assign Azure roles using the Azure portal - Azure RBAC | Microsoft Learn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/role-based-access-control/role-assignments-portal?tabs=delegate-condition)